# What is Robert B. Laughlin saying about quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, superconductivity

[Robert B. Laughlin, *A Different Universe*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465038298) states the following concerning the relationship between superconductivity and quantum field theory. I do not understand why he says "the microscopic equations of quantum mechanics encrypted in the field theory are different from those of the real material and therefore wrong." Could someone explain?

> Reductionist ideology has another fascinating manifestation in superconductivity theory that I call quantum field theory idolatry. Quantum field theory, a body of mathematics that grew out of studies of elementary particles, is commonly taught after conventional quantum mechanics as a special language for working in that subject—and also as kind of superior way of thinking. It is actually not a new way of thinking but simply a restatement of quantum mechanics in the context of the special limitations and conditions appropriate to the vacuum of space. These conditions make the formalism elegant and fun to learn—at least for mathematical types such as myself—but they also make it easy to hide the essence of a thing through manipulation. Sleights of hand can make some physical behavior appear to be caused by field theory when it is actually being caused by the manipulation itself. Shortly after the Bardeen-Cooper-Schrieffer theory was introduced, the language of quantum fields was discovered to be particularly well suited for describing important properties of superconductors—notably the supercurrents themselves, the Meissner effect, the above-threshold conductivity, and the collective sloshing motions of the electrons called plasma oscillations—precisely because it allowed one to postulate one’s way around messy, ultimately unimportant detail and get quickly to the meat of the matter. This eventually led to the practice of explaining all of superconductivity using field theory, and thus indirectly to the idea that quantum fields cause superconductivity. Even today one will find a great many people who secretly believe this. It is ridiculous—like believing that the weather is caused by the price of corn. In fact, quantum field theory works because the emergent universality of superconductivity makes it work, not the other  way around. The microscopic equations of quantum mechanics encrypted in the field theory are different from those of the real material and therefore wrong. The only way one can start from wrong equations and get the right answer is if the property one is calculating is robustly insensitive to details, i.e., is emergent. Thus the lesson from superconductivity is actually not that quantum field theory is a superior computational technology but that quantum fields can themselves emerge.

Comment: I understand you're quoting here, but note how, on a website page, the text becomes a ["wall of text"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wall_of_text).

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine It was I who edited in the quote. It is a bit "wall of text" but that's how it is in the book and I felt obliged to quote the book exactly.

Comment: It was not intended as criticism, just to point out how internet writing seems to necessarily require a different approach than traditional writing (where that passage would not in any way be considered a wall of text).  I'm sorry I wasn't clearer in my intent.

Comment: "one will find a great many people who secretly believe [that qft causes superfluidity]" How does one find them if they believe it secretly? It's like the description of these physicists is different from the real physicists and therefore wrong.

Comment: @tobi_s I think what he meant is one can find such people by listening/reading them, even if they do not tell you explicitly their beliefs. It's similar to how when you listen to a person who makes odd political remarks/references, but never tells you their actual beliefs explicitly, perhaps because they do not have a good argument for them, or they are unacceptable in public discourse. After a while with such person, you may naturally formulate a hypothesis that they make these remarks because they believe various extremist/conspiracy theories, even if they prefer not to say out loud.

Comment: @JánLalinský To do that kind of inference, wouldn't you have to agree what "cause" means in the context of that physical theory? You have objects that describe measurable effects; these objects form a QFT. The interaction term in the theory "causes" superfluidity--in that theory. It also describes an aspect of what happens in the lab. Does it "cause" what happens in the lab? Is that the same belief? And once you're at that point of philosophical dissection, would you claim that you understand the secret lines of thought of your acquaintance? It's a strawman, and not a particularly elegant one.

Comment: @tobi_s No, it's an inference about people, not a scientific argument; I think Laughlin has his idea of what "cause" here means, and that's fine, you or I may have different ideas on meaning/relevance of "cause" in physics, but that's not a concrete actionable objection. Maybe you're reading too much into that quote.

Comment: @tobi_s I understand it as expression of dissatisfaction with the (inferred) mode of thinking of some physicists, where they think qt. field is "real", as in be-able, realistic sense, a thing in physical world to be studied, which is mostly an ungrounded reification of a tool. It is sw. similar to how marxist science ideologues in Soviet block talked about EM field being a form of matter/physical reality - a superfluous ideology,not necessary to explain experiments. Solid state field theory is an approximate description of matter; qt. field is a tool for predictions, not the object of study.

Comment: @JánLalinský his complaint is specifically about "qft causing superfluidity." His next sentence is "It is ridiculous—like believing that the weather is caused by the price of corn." It is not about people. He takes a specific view on what "A cause B" means in the context of physical theories and then ridicules it. This is what is called a strawman. Random physicist: "The $1/r$ potential of gravity causes the Earth to orbit the sun." Laughlin: "That's ridiculous. We use the gravitational potential to describe the collective interaction of the atoms in sun and earth, but it doesn't cause it."

Comment: @tobi_s He detests and ridicules specific view of role and meaning of qft and qf, which he believes is shared by many physicists. I don't see how that is a "strawman". What real problem should he criticize instead? Why do you know better than him what he should criticize?

Comment: He can criticise that view all he wants, I am criticising the rhetorical devices he employs. The sentence "many secretly believe qft causes superfluidity" contains at least three assumptions: 1. many believe X, 2. they do so secretly (so point 1 cannot be disproven), 3. when they secretly believe that qft "causes" sf, they mean a philosophical or physical cause not the one from normal everyday muddled language such as in the sentences "the $1/r$ potential causes things to fall" or "the traffic light caused the cars to stop". He makes those assumptions in order to then spew ridicule.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stopping here. As it tells me "Please avoid extended discussions in comments." I was making a lighthearted joke about his rhetoric and didn't want to end up arguing about what I imagine that he imagines other people are imagining ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I do not understand why he says "the microscopic equations of quantum mechanics encrypted in the field theory are different from those of the real material and therefore wrong." Could someone explain?

What he is trying to say is not super clear.

First, he seems to be arguing that quantum field theory is a sexy formalism and therefore is overused.

Next, he is saying, I think, that if you take some quantum fields and construct some hamiltonian like
$$
\hat H = \int d^3x \psi^\dagger \left(-\frac{\nabla^2}{2m}\right)\psi + \lambda \psi^\dagger \psi^\dagger \psi\psi\;,\tag{1}
$$
then you can derive some equations that describe a superconductor.

But the Hamiltonian in Eq. (1) is for damn sure not the hamiltonian of the real material. The hamiltonian of the real material has a Coulomb interaction between electrons, not some point interaction characterized by a $\lambda$, and the real hamiltonian has the interaction of the electrons with the lattice, and it is, generally, pretty complicated. The fact that we can get away with some relatively simplified field theory is, in his characterization, due to the emergent nature of the phenomena.

This is my take, as a mere mortal. [Maybe better to just email him and ask directly](https://physics.stanford.edu/people/robert-laughlin).

Comment: Is there a theory that is not an *effective* one? After all, we cannot know everything, there is always a detail not yet discovered of which we are not aware. Will there ever be a *real* Hamiltonian of anything, or even if there be a *real Hamiltonian* will that be the end of all discoveries quantum or otherwise?

Comment: It's all relative, the Hamiltonian in the above post is certainly less accurate than one including the Coulomb interactions. That Hamitlonian in turn is less accurate than one which includes the EM field as a dynamic entity...and on it goes.

Comment: There are certainly _ineffective_ theories...

Comment: @JonCuster: Good one! You just earned yourself a brownie point.

Answer (score 22):

It is very common in physics that the fine details of a system can be very complicated, but if we *zoom out* and look at the system from a larger scale it becomes much simpler.

The classical (in both senses) example of this is the [Navier Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) description of fluid flow. At the fine detail we have $10^{23}$ or so molecules in the fluid all interacting with each other, and no computer is powerful enough to calculate how the fluid will flow starting from individual molecules. However if we *zoom out* to a scale many times larger that the size of a molecule we can treat the fluid as a simple continuous medium, and then the equations that describe its flow are relatively simple (though [notoriously hard to solve](https://www.claymath.org/millennium/navier-stokes-equation/)).

In the case of superconductivity the fine detail is even more complicated as we'd have to compute a many body wavefunction for all the particles in the solid. However as with fluid flow we can simplify the problem by ignoring the detail. Superconductivity happens because there is a (very small) attractive force between the conduction electrons. The origin of this force is a complicated interaction between the electrons and vibrations of the crystal lattice, but suppose we ignore the details and just assume some potential curve for this attraction. With this assumption we can write a quantum field theory, [BCS Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCS_theory), that describes the behaviour of the conduction electrons in the presence of this attractive force, and it turns out this theory successfully describes the superconducting properties of the material.

This is where Laughlin's objection comes in. He is pointing out that the quantum field theory ignores the microscopic origin of the attractive force i.e. it is not describing the actual origin of superconductivity. It is an [effective theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_theory) that works only because it ignores the details. I don't think he is objecting to the idea of an effective theory, because ... well ... most physical theories are *effective* to some degree. Rather he is incensed because he believes that physicists have been so seduced by the elegance of quantum field theory that they have forgotten that the theory of superconductivity is *only* an effective theory.

You didn't ask if Laughlin's objects are justified, but assuming the question is implied the answer is yes and no. Ultimately physicists are pragmatists. If a theory successfully predicts the results of experimental observations it's a good theory. If you start criticising the Navier-Stokes equations on the grounds they are an effective theory you will attract looks from aerospace engineers that are at best pitying. However Laughlin is right that we should always remember that our theories are just *descriptions* of our systems and we need to beware of taking them too literally.

Comment: "You didn't ask if Laughlin's objects are justified, but assuming the question is implied the answer is yes and no." I just do not know what he means by "wrong", such is the reason for my question. By "right", does he mean to use the complete Hamiltonian or Lagrangian of the Standard Model?

Comment: @Hans He means _right_ would include the microscopic details of the interactions between the electrons and the lattice vibrations. I doubt he means you need to include the strong and weak forces in the analysis, though maybe he does. I would guess his point is that the interaction of the electrons with the lattice vibrations is not well described by a quantum field theory.

Comment: I use the Standard Model to stress my point of confusion as to which part Laughlin considers wrong, whether it is the fidelity to the *actual* interaction or something else. In case it was the fidelity --- he does say "[the microscopic equation of the quantum mechanics] of the real material" --- I want to leave no stone unturned. But if we are fine with the spirit, then the  electrodynamic interaction amongst the atoms would suffice for being the *right* quantum mechanics of the real material.

Comment: @Hans I think you're taking his comments more seriously than they deserve.

Comment: I do not disagree. The impetus for the enquiry was a friend's emphasis on this passage to demonstrate *emergence* is the right way to do physics as opposed to *reductionism*. I disagree but wanted to decipher what exactly what this statement means before refuting.

Comment: @Hans Physicists have been arguing about this since at least when I was a student forty years ago. Leave your friend with his opinion and get on with enjoying physics!

Comment: What is the most puzzling is what is meant by emergence. I just ask the most concrete question in this passage.

Comment: @Hans He means that the actual makeup "at the bottom", in the smallest detail, is irrelevant or at least uninteresting. The obsessive hunt for ever smaller detail is missing the point. The interesting questions are those of collectives with properties stemming from their collective structure, not their specific microscopic properties. Superconductivity is his example here because (apparently -- I'm in no position to judge) the quantum field theory arrives at interesting and correct results even though it makes wrong assumptions on the microscopic level -- which shows their irrelevancy.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Physicists have been doing this from the very inception of the subject. The simplest example of this method is concentrating only on the center of mass to describe the trajectory of a thrown stone when the air friction is negligible. But is this what is meant by "emergence"? Is the center of mass an emergence? If this is the case, what is new about "emergence"?